# Azure - Share session between two apps

Tags: azure, authentication

I use Azure Portal Login for our internal apps(each has different Azure apps).

Is it possible to share Azure login session between two apps? I mean when i login to one of them it should be logged into other as well

Thanks!

Comment: pretty sure you can achieve that with oauth and tokens

Comment: I already use tokens but seems like an Azure configuration rather than internal thing.

Comment: are they using the same Azure AD Application to auth users?

Comment: No, they use different apps. I have thought about it actually but it needs  to be different since both apps access to different use data.

Comment: well, i suppose that is the culprit, but can you auth to both of them seamlessly if you are using office 365 auth?

Comment: but in this case I will need multiple redirect URLs which is an issue,

Comment: also different apps has different access conditions